# Mutual tangent lines between two functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Given that $f(x) = x^3 - x$ and $g(x) = -(x-3)^2$ find 3 lines, tangent to the graph of $f$ and $g$. How would you find the tangent lines?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The first fundamental question in a calculus course is how to find tangent lines. Think: how have you been finding tangent lines up to now?

Answer (score 0):

Use the usual calculus techniques to find an equation for the tangent line to $f(x)$ where $x=r$. This equation will have variables $x$ and $y$ and the parameter $r$. Simplify the equation to get it into slope-intercept form. The slope of this line is a function of $r$, call it $m_f(r)$, and the same for the $y$-intercept, call it $b_f(r)$.

Now do the same for $g(x)$ at $x=s$, getting functions $m_g(s)$ and $b_g(s)$.

Two tangent lines are equal if they have the same slope and the same $y$-intercept. Therefore you get two simultaneous equations in the two unknowns $r$ and $s$, namely

$$m_f(r)=m_g(s),\quad b_f(r)=b_g(s)$$

Solve these equations for $r$ and $s$, and use these to easily get the desired tangent lines. These equations are not linear, so solving them will not be easy.

By the way, my quick calculations find *four* mutual tangent lines, not just three. I suppose you can show any three of them for a good answer to the question.